# Failing to capture compartment details in OCI using the Terraform

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I wish to create two root compartments "Development" and "UAT" under the existing compartment "Begin1". get the ID of compartment "Development" using IF condition with FOR loop in locals { }

**root folder: variables.tf**

```
 `variable "tenancy_ocid" {
       default="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
  variable "user_ocid" {
      default = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"}

  variable "root_compartment_variables" {
         type = map(object({
            compartment_name = string
            compartment_description = string }))}

   variable "dev_compartment_variables" {
          type = map(object({
               compartment_name = string
               compartment_description = string }))}`
```

**root folder : terraform.tfvars file**

```
    `root_compartment_variables = {
          c1 = { 
             compartment_name = "Development"
             compartment_description = "Compartment for Development resources"
         }
         c2 = { 
             compartment_name = "UAT"
            compartment_description = "Compartment for UAT resources"
         }
      }`
```

**root folder: main.tf**

```
       `provider "oci" {
           tenancy_ocid = "${var.tenancy_ocid}"
           user_ocid = "${var.user_ocid}"
             private_key_path = var.path 
            fingerprint = var.fingerprint
            region = "ap-mumbai-1"
       }

       module "CreateRootCompartment" {
             source  = ".//createcompartment"
              parent_ocid =var.InitialCompartment_OCID    ##Compartment "Begin1" created in OCI
             compartment_variables = var.root_compartment_variables
        }

        locals { 
           dev_compartment_id = [for CMP in module.CreateRootCompartment : CMP ]  
              }

         output "testout1" { value = local.dev_compartment_id   }`
```

**createcompartment folder: main.tf**

```
           `variable "parent_ocid" {} variable "compartment_variables" {type = map}
           resource "oci_identity_compartment" "CreateCompartment" {
                   for_each      =  var.compartment_variables 
                        compartment_id = var.parent_ocid
                         name           = each.value.compartment_name
                        description    = each.value.compartment_description
             }`
```

output "testout1" { value = local.dev_compartment_id} is returning empty.

My wish is that with this ID I can create further child Compartments.